# Faces with separate materials slot are transparent?

Tags: modeling, materials, 3d-view, faces, normals

I'm a beginner, and I'm modelling a hard surface object in Blender 2.93 alpha. I've assigned a different material to some faces to add decals. For some reason, those faces are shown as transparent in the viewport. The normals seem to be okay. Why does this happen? See screenshot below, the faces that are red are the offenders. It seems like they're red because you can see the inside of the model?

[image]

It seems like this issue is mostly a problem when viewing face orientation. Here's a screenshot without the face orientation and normals showing:
[image]

Here's the node setup for one of the decals (had to do a lot of ungrouping) and material properties for the object:
[image]

For some angles, it sort of looks like there are several overlapping faces with opposite normal orientation, but I've tried merging vertices, and it doesn't make any difference.
[image]

Comment: Is the material you assigned them transparent?

Comment: Not really, but it has an alpha image component differentiating between the background material and the decal material. I'll add a rendered view below.

Comment: Show the material nodes and material properties.

Comment: Added a screenshot with the material nodes and properties.

Comment: I don't know if it will fix things, but the Color-Space of your Alpha (mask) image should be non-color (instead of sRGB).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It doesn't make any difference for this issue though.